# Is it legal to take off from the road?

Tags: faa-regulations, safety

Specifically, I'm referring to the takeoff attempt which led to this [crash](https://www.click2houston.com/news/local/2021/10/02/small-plane-crashes-on-intersection-in-chambers-county-deputies-say/) (video [here](https://www.facebook.com/100066869354044/videos/pcb.194596022779375/247963677261167)). This took place on highway 124 in Winnie, TX. Apparently the aircraft had just finished serving as a float in a local parade, and the pilot opted to fly, rather than be towed, back to the airport.

Incredibly, there don't seem to have been any injuries.

In the video, you can see that the police have stopped traffic, but [this article](https://www.12newsnow.com/article/news/local/plane-crash-along-highway-in-winnie/502-826d2150-7b15-4fae-ba78-337a55bee9b3) suggests the local authorities were not involved.

My question is, is this legal? From an FAA regulation standpoint, in particular, but if anyone knows the laws for this area of Texas, I'm interested in that as well. Are there any regulations concerning what a pilot can use for an impromptu runway, and what sort of (obstacle) clearances need to be observed? What sort of permissions does he need to use a public road?

Comment: Guy missed a successful take off by about a foot.

Comment: A tiny bit of right rudder would have kept them clear, but it was still not great judgement.

Comment: In Germany (OK. it's not the USA) it would be forbidden: With exception of rescue aircraft (such as rescue helecopters) you need a permission of the LBA (the German counterpart of the FAA) to take off from any ground outside an airport. You would definitely not get a permission for taking off from a public road. And you would also not get a permission if there are obstacles next to the "runway" (as in the video you have linked).

Comment: Vehicles that use the public roads have to be road legal in the first place, don't they? At least in Europe, airworthy != road legal.

Comment: Jeez. how did clipping the light pole (apparently with the tip of one of the left wings?) cause the plane to lose altitude and crash?  Seems he could have just kept on going --  "The plane can be seen clipping a streetlight and then appears to strike cables holding traffic signal lights"  Oh.  Oopsie!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For this specific case, Texas laws [prohibit](https://texas.public.law/statutes/tex._transp._code_section_24.021) overall the use of public roads for takeoff, still a municipality may issue an ordinance to allow some takeoffs from county roads, describing the specific procedure to be used.

The question boils down to whether such specific ordinance exists for this takeoff. A quick search on for the [aircraft tail number and Chambers county ordinances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22N4106Y%22%20%22chambers%22%20%22ordinance%22&complete=0&uact=5&oq=%22N4106Y%22%20%22chambers%22%20%22ordinance%22) doesn't return anything as of today. It's an [offense](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/offense) unless specifically authorized, though the penalty, a fine between \$25 and \$200, doesn't seem to be a real deterrent.

---

**FAA doesn't regulate off-airport operations**

- FAA requires a [minimal safety height](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.119) over terrain but indeed this doesn't apply for takeoff and landing.
- FAA doesn't regulate off-airport landings/takeoffs, but pilots mustn't be [careless or reckless](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.13).

[image]

<sup>Private helipad in Oregon, [source](https://www.realtor.com/news/unique-homes/seven-homes-with-private-helipads/). Go there with [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@42.5655385,-124.3888042,164m/data=!3m1!1e3)</sup>

**Other entities can regulate or prohibit off-airport operations**

- The insurance may prohibit operations off-airport.
- The State may prohibit the use of public land for specific activities, including for air operations.
- Air operations may be prohibited for purposes of noise protection, natural world protection, etc, so that one's hobby doesn't prevent safety, peace and quite for others.

Whether taking off from a highway is allowed depends on the State.

**Texas and some other States prohibit off-airport operations**

Texas specifically [prohibits](https://texas.public.law/statutes/tex._transp._code_section_24.021) using public roads for takeoff and landing for any [flying object](https://statutes.capitol.texas.gov/Docs/TN/htm/TN.24.htm), manned or not:

> A person commits an offense if the person takes off, lands, or maneuvers an aircraft, whether heavier or lighter than air, on a public highway, road, or street except [...]

Emergency-related landings are indeed never punished and are possible everywhere, and it is conceivable some takeoffs may be emergencies too, but likely not in the present case.

[image]

<sup>Emergency landing in Texas on Interstate 35, [source](https://www.kwtx.com/2021/01/20/pilot-makes-emergency-landing-on-interstate-35/)</sup>

Other exceptions must be specifically [allowed](https://texas.public.law/statutes/tex._transp._code_section_24.022) by a local law maker (commissioners court of a county) using an [ordinance](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/ordinance):

> A commissioners court of a county may enact ordinances to ensure the safe use of county roads by aircraft. An ordinance may:
>
> - (1) limit the kinds of aircraft that may use the roads;
> - (2) establish the procedure that a pilot shall follow before using a road, including requiring the pilot to furnish persons with flags at both ends of the road to be used; or
> - (3) establish other requirements considered necessary for the safe use of the roads by aircraft.

It's possible the operation you saw had been allowed by such local ordinance.

**Some States allow them by default**

In contrast [Montana](https://leg.mt.gov/bills/mca/title_0670/chapter_0010/part_0020/section_0040/0670-0010-0020-0040.html) allows landings and takeoffs in general, though they are still subject to a procedure:

> Aircraft landings and takeoffs from public roads in this state are lawful if proper safety precautions, as approved by the governing jurisdiction of the roads, are taken prior to the landing or takeoff

[image]

<sup>Fields, Oregon, [source](https://backcountrypilot.org/forum/landing-on-roads-in-non-emergency-situation-18765). [How to get there, including the road landing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIS8Y6e_oDM) on Youtube</sup>

---

Of course using a private property is not allowed without prior consent of the owner in addition of regulations mentioned above.

More: [Is It Legal To Land A Plane On A Road?](https://www.aviatortips.com/is-it-legal-to-land-a-plane-on-a-road/)

Comment: A fine between $25 and $200?  Is that cheaper than taking off from an airport?

Comment: @AdamBarnes All but the largest airports in the US are free to use. Some FBOs charge a handling fee, but it’s usually waived if you buy gas or other services from them.

Comment: I feel like when you do a botched takeoff like this where you destroy a pair of traffic lights and utterly wreck your plane, it's going to cost A LOT more than 200 USD.

Comment: What is the relevant definition of a "Public Road" though - if the road has been specifically closed by law-enforcement, does that make it okay?  I ask that, because (in the UK) road-racing is specifically illegal, but only on open roads - temporarily close them officially and it is fine.

Comment: @MikeBrockington Generally speaking, a public road is any road that is on public land, which is any land that *has not been patented*. Notably, govt entities can own non-public land, and that does not automatically make said land public.

Comment: @StephenS  I understand perfectly well what a Public Road is "Generally speaking" - my question was rather specific, and also relevant to the details from the OP, since Law Enforcement may have turned an 'open road' into a 'closed road'.

Comment: @MikeBrockington: A public road where traffic would be stopped for the purpose of a takeoff would still be a public road. Whether law enforcement officers (in contrast with county court commissioners) can allow forbidden acts is another question. I'd say likely, but they bear/share the responsibility of the consequences, like when they allow someone to drive in a one-way street because of a jam, and there is a collision with a car coming from opposite direction.

Comment: RE "Texas specifically prohibit using public roads for takeoff for any flying object, manned or not:"-- would Texas consider a small lightweight radio-controlled model airplane to be an "aircraft"?  Is there any precedent on this?  Your statement seems to imply that such a thing would be prohibited from taking off or landing on public roads but I wonder if that position is really supportable.  And what about a frisbee?

Comment: @quietflyer: Obviously I don't know more than the law says, and replacing "aircraft" by "flying object" is not correct. To answer your question, I imagine Texas has no own definition of aircraft and relies on [FAA one](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/1.1): "*Aircraft means a device that is used or intended to be used for flight in the air.*" Whether models or frisbees are included there is not clear. I'd tend to say yes a tort lawyer may use this against a frisbee user who killed someone.

Comment: And since the FAA is currently using the term "Small Unmanned Aircraft System" to describe model airplanes, drones, etc... from the FAA's viewpoint a model airplane is obviously an aircraft-- but, legally speaking, I don't know that whatever crazy wonky definitions the FAA decides to dream up, really have any legal impact on the interpretation of Texas laws --

Comment: @quietflyer: [*Aircraft* definition for Texas seems to be](https://statutes.capitol.texas.gov/Docs/TN/htm/TN.24.htm): "*a device that is invented, used, or designated for air navigation or flight, other than a parachute or other device used primarily as safety equipment*", so that would definitely include models and likely frisbees.

Answer (score 13):

The FAA does not regulate where aircraft can take off and land. If you want a permanent airport or heliport they have requirements for safe approaches and landings, but only so it can be listed as a facility.

States and local authorities make laws where aircraft can takeoff and land. In [Alaska](https://youtu.be/XQTv0DQtLqg?t=70) use of roads is common, with appropriate consideration of traffic.

[image]

Comment: Indeed. I remember seeing signs on the parks highway cautioning cars to watch for _aircraft_ entering the highway. Even as a pilot, that's not a sign I'm accustomed to seeing on a highway. - haha

Comment: beautiful picture. Looks almost idyllic.

Comment: @lurscher As what life might be like before somebody complained about everything. I like the pic at the beginning of the video which shows the pilot parked at the gas pump getting a fill up.

Answer (score 12):

As far as the FAA is concerned, you can take off from wherever you like. Otherwise seaplanes and helicopters wouldn't be terribly useful.

Local laws vary concerning public roads.

Answer (score 1):

There is a related case in Spain, a man with an Ultralight Autogyro run on the road towards a Gas Station to buy gasoline. He got a fine, even if the road was a common road, not a highway, where vehicles must be able to run faster than 60 km/h, and the machine run on its small wheels never faster than 20 km/ h.
Mopeds, agriculture vehicles are allowed running slowly.
The Spanish State is money-avid, and its personnel suffers a hard craving for having chances of applying sanctions, punishments. Blessings +

Comment: What was the motivation of the fine? We can imagine many reasons, including the lack of driving license or license plate, or driving under influence, or non valid insurance (I'd tend to bet on this one)

Comment: No idea https://youtu.be/nErz9ugCmLA indicates just police action. 
btw: before 'Autogyro', ad of parts seller: 'AutoHero', sound same in Spanish  
La Guardia Cerril de Alicante unidad PEGASO denunció 2 infracciones de tráfico, 1 de seguridad aérea, al piloto de autogiro, español, 38 años, circuló en carretera para repostar. 
Agentes del PEGASO (Policía Especialista en Gestión Aeronáutica y de Seguridad Operacional) Alicante, identificaron y propusieron sanción a un piloto de autogiro, circuló varios km por carretera.
2 de septiembre 2021, carretera CV 815 Castalla (Alicante)
 Blessings +

Comment: Mopeds don't need a driver's license, but it is conceivable that an open propeller is too dangerous to be allowed in road. Salut +