# May an airplane with folding wings legally taxi on the street?

Tags: usa, taxiing, canada, folding-wings

In order for any vehicle larger than a bicycle to be street legal, it must be registered under the state/province's Department/Bureau of Motor Vehicles as a highway vehicle. There already exist light sport airplanes that have folding wings so they can be parked in a standard automobile parking spot, though the tail might stick out a few feet. However, they are intended to be towed to the airfield and not taxied themselves there.

If one simply slaps turn signals, rear parking lights, brake lights, reversing lights, and side mirrors on such an airplane, does it make it road legal to the point where it can be registered under the DMV or BMV? Since FMVSS crashworthiness only applies to auto manufacturers, it does not apply to custom vehicles like Batman cars and Wienermobiles. That is why custom vehicles can be registered under DMV. Also, the tail number of the aircraft satisfies the FMVSS license plate requirement because it is more conspicuous than a license plate. USPS and other US Federal vehicles use large printed numbers to satisfy that requirement.

If such an aircraft is road legal, it is effectively flying car. This would be super useful for road trips, where the drive to the destination can be a conventional drive on the highway, but the return trip can be a flight in order to save time, all with the same vehicle. Furthermore, one can save a lot of money from not having to rent a hangar space by parking at home.

I live in California, where the vehicle safety and pollution laws are strictest in the USA, and want to know about that specifically. What about the Canadian provinces of British Columbia, Ontario, and Quebec, which are possibly even stricter than California?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation Stack Exchange! There will be many roadworthiness requirements that airplanes won't meet if they aren't specifically designed to. The propeller will also be problematic for safety reasons. Also, it might be better to ask this on https://law.stackexchange.com; even though this question is about airplanes, it technically isn't about aviation because it's about the use of airplanes on the ground.

Comment: @Someone - This started at law.se. I recommended here. But yes, it does fall into both realms.

Comment: @WPNSGuy oh okay, thank you. I hadn't seen it there. @ CoastCityLapse00crashtest in that case, please disregard my prior suggestion of asking on Law SE.

Comment: Some people are trying to make the aircraft/car combo work: [PAL-V website](https://www.pal-v.com/en)

Comment: Check https://www.gyromotion.eu/ (autogyro with all car street  stuff, no affiliation).

Comment: Related: [Is it legal to take off from the road?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/89490/3201)

Comment: "_There already exist light sport airplanes that have folding wings_" - looking at photos of some of them it looks like the wings would create a blind spot on the sides, so you would need to install a pair of van mirrors which will have to fold in when flying. Or some type of blind spot cameras. The likely bigger problem is that the wings will create a large side surface area which will be subject to wind buffeting, which might make keeping a lightweight vehicle centered in the lane a challenge in gusty winds. Although I suppose the vertical stabilizer (and rudder?) might help a little.

Comment: The biggest problem isn't mechanical.  It's what do you do when someone runs their car into your $100K+ aircarplane.  Can you afford the collision coverage for it?

Comment: I was on Nauru in 1985, and it was the only international airport I have ever seen where you go through security, [then cross an ordinary road](https://www.flickr.com/photos/46226987@N00/412904835), before boarding the plane. During my stay I went for a walk, and found a Boeing 737 parked beside the road. So different places have different rules (and things may well have changed in 38 years).

Comment: @WayneConrad It is a used light sport aircraft that cost only 40,000 USD. This is just a hypothetical example. It could have been an ultralight aircraft that cost just $25,000 when new (same inflation-adjusted price as Fiesta, Yaris, Fit, and Smart Fortwo before those econoboxes were discontinued in the US). Furthermore, tons of suburban families daily drive a 100K USD SUV, such as a fully loaded Suburban, Expedition EL, and R1S, or a base model Escalade or Navigator, so 100K USD isn't a problem for many people.

Comment: @CoastCityLapse00crashtest All that is true.  But there's a big difference in the necessity and cost of repairs between a car and a certified aircraft.  As WPNSGuy's answer says, 'I can render your Cessna illegal to fly with a hammer. A couple of bashes in the wing, and you'll need, at the least, an inspection. Probably replace the applicable surfaces. Do the same with a car, and...meh. It still drives OK.'

Comment: @CoastCityLapse00crashtest *"If one simply slaps turn signals, rear parking lights, brake lights, reversing lights, and side mirrors on **[ ANYTHING ]**, does it make it road legal to the point where it can be registered under the DMV or BMV"*  Of course not. Absolutely not. The question is somewhat nonsensical. It's incredibly difficult / typically simply impossible to get "some home made construction" registered as a real car.

Comment: "That is why custom vehicles (the weiner mobile etc) can be registered under DMV"  they're not custom vehicles. They're completely conventional well-known vehicles (almost always "A Ford F-150") with *modifications*.  (Note that indeed in many jurisdictions, such things are simply totally illegal and unheard of. A trivial example is that in Australia, say, as a rule you can't even 'raise' a pickup truck, as is commonplace in the US. In Austria it's totally illegal to "chip" an engine.)

Comment: How do you plan to apply torque to the drive axle?  Halfshaft? Electric?   Will the engine need to be running and if so, how do you manage to stop the prop?   Or will it be guarded?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica The airplane will just taxi on the street, but with its wings unbolted and stowed on the sides or on the roof. No torque will be applied to the axles because it doesn't have a driveshaft. The propeller will have a removable guard to protect external objects from propeller strikes. In fact, the guard will be made soft enough to meet EU pedestrian safety requirements.

Comment: @CoastCityLapse00crashtest It seems like you're convinced the answer is "yes, definitely." Give it a try and let us know how it works out! ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When driving on roads there is no such category as flying car. You must meet the regulations for the vehicle class in question, and if the vehicle can also fly that is a separate matter.

The most expedient way to do this is to classify the vehicle as a motorcycle. This is defined as a vehicle with no more than three wheels such as this vehicle, the [1800lb](https://spectrum.ieee.org/exclusive-3wheeled-aptera-reboots-as-worlds-most-efficient-electric-car) [Aptera](https://www.electrive.com/2023/01/23/aptera-presents-the-launch-edition-of-its-solar-trike/), considered a trike. This is a normal configuration for most aircraft.

[image]

The [regulations](https://www.clearviewshields.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/NHTSA-Requirements-for-Motorcycle-Manufacturers.pdf) are far less stringent: no crash testing, no EPA (or [CARB](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/vehicle-registration/new-registration/register-a-motorcycle/)) emissions/fuel economy testing required, etc. In fact, here is the entire list of FMVSS regs that apply to motorcycles, mopeds or motor driven cycles, including three
wheeled vehicles:

1. FMVSS No. 106, Brake Hoses
2. FMVSS No. 108, Lamps, Reflective Devices, and Associated Equipment
3. FMVSS No. 111, Rearview Mirrors
4. FMVSS No. 116, Motor Vehicle Brake Fluids
5. FMVSS No. 119, New Pneumatic Tires for Vehicles Other Than Passenger Cars
6. FMVSS No. 120, Tire Selection and Rims for Vehicles Other Than Passenger Cars
7. FMVSS No. 122, Motorcycle Brake System
8. FMVSS No. 123, Motorcycle Controls and Displays
9. FMVSS No. 205, Glazing Materials
10. 49 CFR 565, Vehicle Identification Number Content Requirement
11. 49 CFR 574, Tire Identification and Recordkeeping
12. 49 CFR 575.6(a)(2)(I), Consumer Information
13. 49 CFR 576, Record Retention

So slap some wings on an Aptera (if they ever go into production) and go flying. Emissions paranoid places will love you because the aptera is electric, at least on the ground. You might be able to use the included battery for flight with a suitable electric motor and prop.

I'm not a fan of electric aircraft due to weight and flying cars have to make a lot of compromises, but this shows that a road legal vehicle can be aerodynamic and lightweight enough to use as a fuselage. Use of electric wheel motors on the ground means you don't have to have a spinning prop in traffic, and cutting back on battery capacity to accommodate local ground use only might have some chance of working.

Comment: Nah, with the included battery good luck getting a 1.5 ton body to fly. by adding wings and fuselage - a cessna skyhawk weighs 1.1 tons dry all inclusive. The Aptera would be 80% dead weight.

Comment: @Trish The Aptera was intended as an example only, but you are mistaken in stating that it weighs 3000lb. With the 60kw battery it is 1800lb, less than your skyhawk. That does not include any wings, propulsion or tail. I'm not a fan of electric aircraft and flying cars have to make a lot of compromises, but this shows that a road legal vehicle can be aerodynamic and lightweight. Use of electric wheel motors on the ground means you don't have to have a spinning prop in traffic, and cutting back on battery for local ground use only might have some chance of working.

Comment: @Pilothead The basic empty weight of a Skyhawk is less than 1700 pounds. It will be heavier with a pilot of course but the same is true of the Aptera. And 60 kWh is the equivalent of about 10 pounds of avgas. Per the POH a Skyhawk uses about that just for engine start, taxi, and takeoff.

Comment: @pilothead With solid-state batteries coming circa 2028 for production automobiles, weight wouldn't be a problem. This is especially since the non-flammability of all-solid state batteries (being made from ceramics/glasses) makes batteries doubling as structural members a safe and practical reality.

Comment: Since the Aptera is already practically an airplane fuselage, I wouldn't be surprised if Aptera just attaches wings, propeller(s) driven by compact electric hub motors, and an empennage to the production vehicle planned to be released model year 2025 when solid-state batteries become available later on that make the plane light enough to fly economically. Furthermore, the infotainment system of all modern road vehicles has more than enough computing power to support avionics, so Aptera can also just slap antennas integrated into the windshield that connects directly to the infotainment system.

Comment: @Chris LOL no, 60kWh is equivalent to the energy in 10 lbs of gas only for silly comparisons like burning the gas in a space heater vs. powering an electric heater with the battery. ICEs are horrifically inefficient at turning fuel into motion. 60 kWh into a motor is equivalent to more like 30 or 40 lbs of gas into an engine.

Comment: @nobody 10 lbs or 30 lbs, the point is it's *very* little for a Skyhawk. With 30 lbs of fuel you'd be around the legal VFR limit just to do one lap around the pattern!

Comment: So remove the battery and solar panels from the Aptera, add an ICS to drive a propeller in flight and produce electricity for the electric motor(s) on the road. Let's add a fuel tank, wings and enough VFR instruments to qualify as an experimental aircraft ... what dry weight are we down to now?

Comment: @CoastCityLapse00crashtest Why do you think weight wouldn't  be a problem with solid-state batteries? [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_battery) mentions their specific energy as around 400 W-h/kg. [The specific energy of most hydrocarbon fuels is around 12,000-13,000 W-h/kg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density) and Lithium metal batteries are around 500. We are minimally decades from having a production-ready battery chemistry that can come close to rivaling hydrocarbon fuels for specific energy at the scale of a vehicle, nevermind certified for aviation.

Comment: @reirab The thing is, technological inventions are unpredictable. Sure, innovation is continual refinement, which happens at a relatively predictable rate. However, inventions totally change the world once it is practically commercially deployed. After all, no one thought how electricity would revolutionize the world until electromagnetism was accidentally discovered, which made electricity generation quick and economical. With solid-state batteries, someone could accidentally discover tomorrow a chemistry that gets the same specific energy as hydrocarbons as enabled by high EN difference.

Comment: @CoastCityLapse00crashtest Technology will advance for sure, but, in relatively mature fields, the rate of advancement is more predictable than you might think. It is _exceptionally_ unlikely that someone will discover a battery chemistry that rivals hydrocarbon fuels soon that can be scaled to use for vehicles while also being commercially viable to produce and sufficiently stable for safe use in vehicles that often crash into each other, let alone vehicles that _fly_. It's not impossible, but it's exceptionally unlikely to happen soon.

Answer (score 7):

Unlikely. Some problems:

- Putting additional lights on vehicles is illegal per [CVC 24003](https://www.lawserver.com/law/state/california/codes/california_vehicle_code_24003) (California Vehicle Code). You'd need an aircraft with no navigation lights, landing light, etc.
- Per [CVC 26311](https://www.lawserver.com/law/state/california/codes/california_vehicle_code_26311), every wheel needs brakes.
- Smog testing is probably an issue unless the airframe is old enough to be exempted.
- [CVC 27200](https://www.lawserver.com/law/state/california/codes/california_vehicle_code_27200) prescribes noise limits, which many aircraft would not comply with.
- [CVC 27400](https://www.lawserver.com/law/state/california/codes/california_vehicle_code_27400) forbids drivers from wearing headphones. This kind of fits in with the last one- pilots wear headsets for a reason!
- Brakes are likely a problem. Motor vehicles are required to have service brakes and parking brakes, and they must be redundant in specific ways that aircraft brakes may not be. The maximum stopping distances may also be problematic.
- You need windshield wipers.
- You need a windshield constructed of "safety glazing material." Yours may or may not be already, but aircraft windshields are not required to be.

I'm sure this list is not exhaustive.

From a practical standpoint it would be a *bad* road vehicle, since it would be slow, have poor gas mileage, kick up rocks something awful, and have a spinny blade of death on it that will badly damage anything it touches but also can do thousands of dollars worth of damage to itself if it so much as hits a rock.

Comment: ... or if the spinny blade of death gets hit by someone else's rock.  Worse than one more chip in the windshield, for both the vehicle and whatever catches the ricochet.

Comment: One can just turn off the navigation lights in order to comply with CVC 24003. Just installing them isn't a problem because commercial vehicles have other lights, especially advertisement screens on top of taxis and ride hailing vehicles. Aren't all wheels braked on an airplane, thus complying with CVC 26311? Airplanes obviously have service brakes for landing. Don't they also have parking brakes for the apron and hangar?

Comment: This also assumes the airplane not only meets CARB LEV III, but also is a SULEV that can take 87 AKI octane regular unleaded MoGas (in addition to leaded 100LL RON AvGas) so that it meets the CARB requirement when using that fuel. Airplanes are much quieter when taxiing because the propellor spins slower, so CVC 27200 shouldn't be an issue. Also, headphones won't be used when cruising on public roads because it is not loud enough to warrant that. It is probably only as loud as diesel engine when inside the cockpit, so CVC 27400 shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Also, most airplanes have a windshield because they are able to travel at high speeds. In fact, they have to meet much more stringent requirements. Obviously, those airplanes also have windshield wipers. With regards to headlights, don't landing lights comply with the requirement with highway high beam headlights? If low beans are also required, can't one just add a dinmer circuit?

Comment: Airplanes rely on the air to travel, so they have a much lower drag coefficient than cars. So, shouldn't they get better gas mileage when taxiing/driving? Also, is the propeller powerful enough to kick up rocks when it only on taxi throttle? Regarding the spinning blade of death, one can also install a removable cowling just like with pedestal fans to protect external people. Then at the airfield, one can just remove and stow the cowling so that it does not interfere with the aerodynamics of flight.

Comment: @CoastCityLapse00crashtest Most aircraft have brakes on the mains but not on the nosewheel/tailwheel. Airplanes are quiet*er* while taxiing slowly but they're still pretty darn loud and extremely loud at freeway speeds. Airplanes may or may not have a lower drag coefficient but using a propeller to drag yourself across the ground is really, really inefficient. The propeller can easily kick up rocks even at taxi throttle, but in any case you're going to be at quite a bit higher throttle to be at "reasonable road vehicle" speeds.

Comment: Aircraft have parking brakes, but typically all they do is actuate the service brakes. CA vehicle code requires that no single point of failure outside of the wheel brake assembly itself can take out both the service and parking brakes. Aircraft have no such requirement. A cowling helps with the spinny blade of death but makes your gas mileage even worse and poses problems for visibility.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune I take offense to that. It is a spinny blade of life...for the pilot!

Comment: @CoastCityLapse00crashtest "*So, shouldn't they get better gas mileage when taxiing/driving?*" No. Slow taxi speeds make the drag advantage of airplanes relative to cars irrelevant. Propellers also have inferior coupling for momentum transfer on the ground compared to driven wheels. Airplane engines and propellers are also optimized for high efficiency at flight speeds with little attention, if any, on the efficiency while taxiing. Indeed, taxxing efficiency is gladly sacrificed for flight efficiency.

Comment: @CoastCityLapse00crashtest In other words, airplanes have terrible TERRIBLE efficiency on the ground.

Comment: @CoastCityLapse00crashtest "Obviously, those airplanes also have windshield wipers." Nope! Windshield wipers are unusual in general aviation aircraft. They aren't that useful in flight and even in airliners that have them they're mainly used while on the ground.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like someone is *seriously* underestimating the complexity of this enterprise.

> I wouldn't be surprised if Aptera just attaches wings, propeller

> Aptera can also just slap antennas integrated into the windshield that connects directly to the infotainment system

If we consider the above mentioned Aptera car, and a similar weight Cessna 172...

The wingspan of the Skyhawk is 11 meters. Subtract the fuselage from that, and you end up with wings about 4.5 meters. Which is the full length of the Aptera at 4.5 meters. So where do you put these when driving around town? Remember, they can't obstruct visibility.

In both realms, the vehicle is hauling around extra weight. On the ground, the flight control surfaces and prop. In the air, roadable suspension. A car can generally withstand a big pothole at 50mph. Not good for the car, but not critical. Go ahead and hit that same pothole at 50mph with the front wheel of the Cessna.

Crashworthiness? I can render your Cessna illegal to fly with a hammer. A couple of bashes in the wing, and you'll need, at the least, an inspection. Probably replace the applicable surfaces. Do the same with a car, and...meh. It still drives OK.

*Can* this be done? Probably. But it will NOT be cheap or easy.

A flyable Aptera will be significantly heavier than its road counterpart.

FAA, NHTSA, state inspections, all will come into play.

In response to the comment on '**visibility**', here is a pic of an Aptera, and the Aptera with an overlay of a Cessna 172 wing. Pretty much to scale, both at 4.5m long.

A wing that size is needed to get an aircraft of that weight and power in the air.

[image]

Aptera pic from [TheVerge](https://www.theverge.com/2021/4/1/22358355/aptera-ev-three-wheeled-doe-atvm-loan-program).
Wing planform from [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_172#/media/File:Dreiseitenansicht_Cessna_172.svg)

Comment: Yes, a few bashes of the flight control surfaces will render the plane inoperable. However, bashes that are hard enough to dent structural metal are uncommon enough that it isn't a problem. If they were such a huge problem, then bush planes wouldn't exist because they need to land on open fields.

Comment: Also, the wings on an Aptera won't obstruct the legally required visibility because even with them folded up on the side, the visibility is still better than with people with 2.5 and 3.5 ton lifted pickup trucks.

Comment: Arranged with intent you could obstruct the view with a school lunch tray.)

Comment: @Pilothead - Just going by the commenters statement of "folded up on the side". A lunch tray, you could put anywhere. A thing that is larger than the car...not so much.

Comment: @CoastCityLapse00crashtest Not sure that I understand your comments about lifted trucks. You can see quite well to the sides from those. It's everyone else who has a problem seeing past you.

Comment: In response to the picture, the wing will be unbolted and stowed longitudinally on top of the wing box the roof, where it will also not obstruct the doors. I don't know how heavy each wing is, but if each are only 100 pounds or less, then the 2 occupants can simply lift them on top of the roof after unbolting. The weight of even a pneumatic torque wrench and air compressor powering it are proportionally negligible to the airplane, so even that will be carried on-board. Of course, a hand torque wrench will be much more lightweight.

Comment: I suppose you'd want to take the wings apart. Putting a purpose-made large airfoil on top of your car seems like an incredible way to crash your car on a gusty day!

Comment: Put the wings on top? I can't imagine they weigh less that 200lbs each. And oh yeah...the top is where the Aptera solar panels are.

Comment: Here is where Aska put the wings: https://newatlas.com/aircraft/aska-a5-vtol-flying-car/

Answer (score 4):

Sure, the CAA (FAA precursor) [certified the Aerocar in 1956](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerocar) and 6 examples were actually produced with folding wings and a [road capable car](https://www.motortrend.com/vehicle-genres/aerocar-history-generations-models/) body. There is still at least one that is airworthy. Granted the road regulations at the time we not quite the same as today.

If its gas or powerplant your worried about, the [Porsche 3.2L Carrera engine was at one point certified for flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porsche_PFM_3200) and there are [MoGas conversions for common aviation engines out there](https://www.autofuelstc.com/order_online.phtml). There are also aircraft [running more modern Jet-A (read diesel) engines](https://www.diamondaircraft.com/en/private-owners/aircraft/da42/overview/) that you could use to build such a craft.

Dealing with the DOT to get it passed all the certifications for safety *and* keeping it light enough to be a functional airplane is going to be tricky at best but there is nothing explicitly preventing it.

However you [might not be able to park it at home](https://www.fox5ny.com/news/man-parks-plane-in-driveway) and you likely [cant just land anywhere](https://archive.nytimes.com/cityroom.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/06/04/long-ago-a-pilot-landed-on-an-uptown-street-thats-where-the-bar-was/) even if you ["think" its for landing](https://highways.dot.gov/highway-history/interstate-system/50th-anniversary/interstate-highway-system-myths#question5).

Comment: Fortunately, keeping it light enough to fly while complying with even DOT crashworthiness regulations shouldn't be a problem. That is because DOT regulations are regarding property damage and occupant protection of the vehicle against a stationary object. Since the plane has to be so lightweight to fly anyway, it'll only have fairly small inertial forces that it has to resist at the speeds the 5-mph bumper and 30-mph crash tests are done at. Furthermore, since the 1990s, the bumper requirement has been lowered to 2.5 mph. I wouldn't be surprised if an unmodified airplane aces all crash tests.

Comment: On the other hand, making a rail vehicle with folding wings that runs with freight trains that can also fly would be next to impossible without the chassis being completely made out of carbon fibre or titanium alloys. That is because the FRA has long required a buff strength of 800,000 pounds. Since 2020, however, the FRA has required PTC on all railroads, and the buff strength requirement with PTC is the EU standard of 300,000 lb. So, even a stainless steel airplane with folding wings can also be FRA-compliant under current engineering methods, though likely with poor gas mileage when flying.

Answer (score 0):

Most foldable-wing aircraft aren't street legal, however, the [Terrafugia Transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrafugia_Transition) does have this as a design goal. It was announced in 2006 and its first flight was in 2009. Its first delivery was planned for 2011... and that still hasn't happened, nor is there even currently a firm delivery timeline. It did receive a Light-Sport Aircraft Airworthiness Certificate from the FAA in 2021, but then the company soon after announced that it was closing down its operations in the U.S. and moving to China. I haven't heard any updates on them since then.

Meeting the requirements to be legal to drive on streets in the U.S. while keeping its weight low enough to be reasonable for an airplane has been a huge challenge, to say the least.

Comment: It could simply be that the company is not well-funded due to lack of investors rather than being an engineering challenge. After all, being able to start commercial production is way, way harder than engineering a hand-built one that works as intended. That is because production line equipment is super expensive.

Comment: @CoastCityLapse00crashtest The problem for them has always been engineering, specifically, getting it to be street-legal while also able to fly with reasonable efficiency. Actually fabricating it is relatively cheap compared to designing it and getting it simultaneously certified for both flight and driving on roads. This is pretty much always the case with aviation, which is why manufacturers are still building aircraft based on designs originally certified in the 50s or 60s. (Engineer who has worked as such at one of the world's most capable aviation R&D testing facilities here.)

Comment: @CoastCityLapse00crashtest - It could also be that you are simply applying copious amounts of handwavium to the significant engineering and regulatory issues. No one has said this is "impossible". But it ain't easy or cheap.